# How to determine if stdin is empty

Tags: c

I have a little project to do for school. We have a program that generate a maze.
We can put arguments to generate a different maze or even get it as a picture.

We call it like that :

> ./test

or

> ./test --arg1 val --arg2 val --etc

We have been asked to parse the argument into a file that we put in stdin like that :

> ./test  < args.txt

Now I must be able to call the program with every one of the lines above. The line with the arguments work, the mine with the program in stdin works, but the line without anything doesnt work anymore.

So i should check if the user as sent some file in stdin i call the program with a file, else i call it the normal way. I tried with feof but it can't work since stdin won't have anything in not even eof.
When i call the program without arguments or file it waits for the user to write something, which it shouldnt.

Basically my code should look like that

```
int main()
{
    int v;
    if (stdin!=NULL)) { //if a file has been passed "./test <test.txt"
        scanf("%d",&v);
    }
    else {  //if no files has been passed "./test "
        printf("no file forwarded \n"); 
        return 1;
    }
    if (v<50) {
        printf("you drive slow\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("you drive fast\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But obviously `(stdin != NULL)` doesn't work. So is there a way to check if stdin has something in?
I asked my classmate, one of them told me something about useing fgetc to get the first char and then put it back if there is really a char but when i try to use fgetc, if there is no char it waits for me to put a char in.

So how could I check if stdin is empty or if there is a file into it (without using new libraries)?

Thanks you in advance
have a good day

If i am not completely clear please tell it to me i am not a native speaker and i have a bit of difficulties since it's a technical question

Comment: Many programs that wish to read arguments from a file take @filename as an argument to open that file name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you want to run your program based on arguments either provided on the command line or piped into it from a file. If so, you should check whether the arguments have been provided on the command line first:

```
if (argc > 1) {
  //parse argv
}
```

Then, check whether stdin is empty, and if not read the arguments in from stdin:

```
else if ((fseek(stdin, 0, SEEK_END), ftell(stdin)) > 0)
{
  rewind(stdin);
  char buffer[1024];
  fgets(buffer, 1024 , stdin);
  //parse args read in from stdin
}
else
{
  //no redirection
}
```

Comment: feof allways returns 0 since stdin won't have eof in it. 
i want to be able to call the program without arguments, with arguments or with a file
For the moment i can call it only with arguments or with a file

Comment: If you call it without arguments you will know that by looking at `argc`. If you provide a file with `./test < file` `feof` will not return 0 and you know that way. What is the problem?

Comment: when i try with feof it doesnt work at all perhaps i'm missusing it i'll try again
i edited my question with an example code
to be more precise when i use feof
if i ask with arguments it works fine
if i ask with a file it works fine
if i ask without arguments or file it waits for an input (which shouldnt be the case)

when i put a file !feof(stdin) return 0, and when i don't it returns 0 too

Comment: It waits for input when there are no arguments because you have the `scanf` in there, if you don't want to wait for input just take the `scanf` out. I must be missing something...

Comment: okay so:
if i provide a file it should read it (so it uses scanf to read the file which was provided) 
if i don't provide a file it gives an error 
(this program is just a simplified version)

it should check if there is a file provided in the stdin or not so it shouldnt wait for an input when there is no file. feof doesnt work since it allways return the same things file or not. Try the code on your machine you will see what i'm talking about

Comment: OK I just did check, if you want to stay within `stdio.h` (nothing external) the `fseek` `ftell` combination works to tell whether anything was piped in. Updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

Okay i found a solution it is not the best one since i shouldn't use external libraries but for now it works, i hope it will be usefull for someone :

feof was a good idea but indeed it doesn't work, the reason is stdin will never have EOF in it if you worte nothing in it. So if you provide a file since you must parse the file when there is no file it will try to parse what the user types in.

first you must include

```
#include <unistd.h>
```

then

```
int v;
    if (!isatty(STDIN_FILENO)) //if stdin is not a terminal (a file was provided)
    {
         scanf("%d",&v);
    }
    else { //if stdin is a terminal (no file provided)
        printf("no file forwarded \n"); 
        return 1;   
    }
    if (v<50){printf("you drive slow\n");}
    else {printf("you drive fast\n");}
    return 0;
```

it will check if stdin is a terminal or not. 
This solution works but if someone has one without the use of external libraries it would be super cool !

Comment: `isatty()` is not part of the standard C library.  Neither is `<unistd.h>`.

Answer (score 2):

> How to determine if stdin is empty(?)

Read 1 character with  `getchar()`.

```
int ch = getchar();
if (ch == EOF) {
  if (feof(stdin)) puts("stdin empty");
  else             puts("stdin error"); // very rare
} else {
  ungetc(ch, stdin); // put back
  puts("stdin not empty");
}
```

Comment: I hate you, but this is the right answer.
If you ask how to do other useful things, like how to determine the size of stdin, you'll be met with the same exact answer. Stdin wasn't meant to have future sight, so we're stuck doing hacky things.
That being said, not sure if you'd always be able to ungetc into stdin given it's not always a file, at least on all platforms.

Comment: @LeifMessingerLOAF Re: "not sure if you'd always be able to ungetc", Pushing one back is OK. "One character of pushback is guaranteed. If the ungetc function is called too many times on the same stream without an intervening read or file positioning operation on that stream, the operation may fail"